# How do I get the HTML of an active chrome browser?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am currently working on creating a Qlearning bot for the browser game Agar.io for a university project. In order to accurately define reward for the bot, I need the score shown in bottom left part of the screen. Currently I'm cropping a screenshot (a screenshot I am using anyway) and using pytesseract (a text recognition program) to read the digits shown, but this takes about 0.3 seconds, and I need the delay between taking an image and performing an action to be as short as possible since the game is in real time, so the bot acts on current information and actually is where it thinks it is. The entire process takes about 0.45 seconds, so reading the score accounts for about 2/3 on average.

I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing it, perhaps by searching for where the score is displayed in the HTML. I've just wrapped up my first semester and am familiar with python, but that's about it. I know next to nothing about HTML, but I am willing to learn. I have tried using selenium, but Agar.io blocks automated browsers (currently I am using pynput to manually open a browser and start the game), and I haven't figured out how to get around it. There might be a way to request the information, but I am way out of my depth there. Are there any other tools I can use? And if so, how would I use them? Thanks in advance!

I've tried using selenium like this

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH,options=option)

browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

browser.get("https://agar.io/")
```

Comment: You can probably (maybe) get around the script-blocking by setting headers for the webdriver. Google specifically for agar.io and selenium headers. I'm sure someone has done it before, as agar.io is very popular. You're also going to have to learn about HTML, Javascript, and HTTP headers. This won't be an easy task for someone with very little to no domain knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up optimizing the image recognition further and delaying reading the score, so the program now responds fast enough for the actions to be relevant. Thanks for the help. I look forward to learning about all that in the future.